# Asymptotic Analysis of Algorithms:how to insert k new elements into a sorted list of size n in time O(k log k + n)

Tags: algorithm

This example demonstrates how to determine the index at which an element should be inserted into a sorted list. Although binarySearch() is used to locate existent elements, it can also be used to determine the insert index for non-existent elements.

```
// Create a list with an ordered list of items 
List sortedList = new LinkedList(); 
sortedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"}));
// Search for the non-existent item int index = Collections.binarySearch(sortedList, "cow"); 
// -4 // Add the non-existent item to the list 
if (index < 0) { sortedList.add(-index-1, "cow"); }
```

How I cant to insert elements for time O(k log k + n).
k is the number of lists.
n is the total number of elements in all of the lists (n = n1 + n2 + ... + nk).

Explain in Asymptotic Analysis of Algorithms???

Comment: @MSN: Please stop adding the homework tag without any clarification from OP.

Comment: @Moron, ah, my bad. Given the text, I should have googled the first paragraph first: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_InsertInList.html

Comment: Not being familiar with java LinkedList, does it really support binary search?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it deserves a homework flag, so I won't spoil it totally for you, but review your very classical sort algorithms and don't think of it as inserting elements, think of it as creating a still ordered list that contains all elements from both lists.